# Instance of class in c++

Tags: c++, class

I woud like to ask what is the difference between this

```
Tv *television = new Tv();
```

and

```
Tv television = Tv();
```

Comment: You don't need to do `Tv television = Tv();`, you can do `Tv television;`

Comment: Strongly suggest you read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: @xiaomao there is difference between `T i;` and `T i = T();` for all POD types.

Comment: To accept an answer, click the check mark next an answer (but only if that answer has helped). To find your other questions, click on your username, go to the **Questions** section, and click on a question you asked and do the same.

Comment: @PiotrNycz didn't know about that. Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: @xiaomao the construct `T t = T();` means that t is zero initialized, like `int i = int();` means that i is equal to zero, whilst `int i;` means that i contains garbage unless it is global,

Answer (score 5):

The first one creates a dynamically allocated `Tv` and binds it to a pointer to `Tv`. The duration of the `Tv` object is under your control: you decide when to destroy it by calling `delete` on it.

```
new Tv(); // creates dynamically allocated Tv and returns pointer to it
Tv* television; // creates a pointer to Tv that points to nothing useful
Tv* tv1 = new Tv(); // creates dynamicalls allocated Tv, pointer tv1 points to it.

delete tv1; // destroy the object and deallocate memory used by it.
```

The second one creates an [automatically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) `Tv` by [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm). The duration of the `Tv` object is automatic. It gets destroyed deterministically, according to the rules of the language, e.g. on exiting scope:

```
{
  // copy-initializaiton: RHS is value initialized temporary.
  Tv television = Tv(); 
} // television is destroyed here.
```

"exiting scope" may also refer to the end of the life of an object of a class that contains a `Tv` object:

```
struct Foo {
  Tv tv;
}

....
{
  Foo f;
} // f is destroyed, and f.tv with it.
```

Comment: Dynamic, automatic: What's the difference?

Comment: @David, dynamic objects have to be deleted with `delete`, automatic will automatically go out of the scope and get destroyed.

Comment: Dynamic objects are allocated from the heap; automatic objects are created on the stack.  (Creating an object on the stack is a bit more efficient, since all the compiler has to do is increase the value of the stack pointer by sizeof(Tv) and then call the object's constructor; but the lifetime of an object on the stack is always equal to the lifetime of the function/method that declared it, which isn't always what you want)

Comment: @David I hope it is clear from my edits. Note that I avoided all mentions of "heap" and "stack" because the C++ standard makes no mention of those. But people often use the term "stack" for automatic allocation and "heap" for dynamic.

Comment: @juanchopanza Your answered cleared up much confusion I had. Thanks. +1